# Creating a ViewModel causes the app to crash. (Kotlin/Android Studio)

Tags: android, kotlin, viewmodel

I have been following a tutorial from Geeks for Geeks on how to make a simple note app for Android. I've practically copied to code word-by-word (except for a minor fix in the gradle file as advised from a Stack Overflow post and a comment in the YouTube comment section), yet the app crashes every time I open it even after clearing all the caches and rebuilding the project.

Links:

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-build-a-simple-note-android-app-using-mvvm-and-room-database/
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D2F5t-phP04

Now, I know the problem with the code stems from the below command line.

```
viewModel = ViewModelProvider(
    this, 
    ViewModelProvider.AndroidViewModelFactory.getInstance(application)
).get(NoteViewModel::class.java)
```

Every time I include the above line and launch the app, the app crashes, and my phone cannot open it. Commenting out the above line and the code below it allows the app to be opened without an issue.

(App gradle)

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
}

android {
    compileSdk 32

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.notepractice"
        minSdk 26
        targetSdk 32
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/atomicfu.kotlin_module'
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:$rootProject.appCompatVersion"
    implementation "androidx.activity:activity-ktx:$rootProject.activityVersion"

    // Dependencies for working with Architecture components
    // You'll probably have to update the version numbers in build.gradle (Project)

    implementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.1.0'

    // Room components
    implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:$rootProject.roomVersion"
    annotationProcessor "androidx.room:room-compiler:$rootProject.roomVersion"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.room:room-testing:$rootProject.roomVersion"

    // Lifecycle components
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.2.0"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.2.0"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.2.0"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common-java8:$rootProject.lifecycleVersion"

    // Kotlin components
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    api "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:$rootProject.coroutines"
    api "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:$rootProject.coroutines"

    // UI
    implementation "androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:$rootProject.constraintLayoutVersion"
    implementation "com.google.android.material:material:$rootProject.materialVersion"

    // Testing
    testImplementation "junit:junit:$rootProject.junitVersion"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.arch.core:core-testing:$rootProject.coreTestingVersion"
    androidTestImplementation ("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:$rootProject.espressoVersion", {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.ext:junit:$rootProject.androidxJunitVersion"
}
```

(Project gradle)

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = "1.5.31"
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle-api:7.2.1"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.2.0' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.2.0' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.7.10' apply false
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
/*
ext {
    activityVersion = '1.4.0'
    appCompatVersion = '1.4.0'
    constraintLayoutVersion = '2.1.2'
    coreTestingVersion = '2.1.0'
    coroutines = '1.5.2'
    lifecycleVersion = '2.4.0'
    materialVersion = '1.4.0'
    roomVersion = '2.3.0'
    // testing
    junitVersion = '4.13.2'
    espressoVersion = '3.4.0'
    androidxJunitVersion = '1.1.3'
}

 */
ext {
    activityVersion = '1.2.3'
    appCompatVersion = '1.3.0'
    constraintLayoutVersion = '2.0.4'
    coreTestingVersion = '2.1.0'
    coroutines = '1.5.0'
    lifecycleVersion = '2.3.1'
    materialVersion = '1.3.0'
    roomVersion = '2.3.0'
    // testing
    junitVersion = '4.13.2'
    espressoVersion = '3.1.0'
    androidxJunitVersion = '1.1.2'
}
```

(Main Activity)

```
package com.example.notepractice

import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.activity.viewModels
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.lifecycle.Observer
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
import java.util.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), NoteClickInterface, NoteClickDeleteInterface {

    lateinit var viewModel: NoteViewModel
    lateinit var notesRV: RecyclerView
    lateinit var addFAB: FloatingActionButton

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        notesRV = findViewById(R.id.RVNotes)
        addFAB = findViewById(R.id.FABAddNote)

        notesRV.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)

        val noteRVAdapter = NoteRVAdapter(this, this, this)

        notesRV.adapter = noteRVAdapter

        viewModel = ViewModelProvider(
            this, 
            ViewModelProvider.AndroidViewModelFactory.getInstance(application)
        ).get(NoteViewModel::class.java)

        /*
        viewModel.allNotes.observe(this, Observer { list ->
            list?.let {
                noteRVAdapter.updateList(it)
            }
        })

        addFAB.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(this@MainActivity, AddEditNoteActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
            this.finish()
        }

         */
    }

    override fun onNoteClick(note: Note) {
        val intent = Intent(this@MainActivity, AddEditNoteActivity::class.java)

        intent.putExtra("noteType", "Edit")
        intent.putExtra("noteTitle", note.noteTitle)
        intent.putExtra("noteDescription", note.noteDescription)
        intent.putExtra("noteId", note.id)

        startActivity(intent)
    }

    override fun onDeleteIconClick(note: Note) {
        viewModel.deleteNote(note)
        Toast.makeText(this, "${note.noteTitle} Deleted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }
}
```

(ViewModel)

```
package com.example.notepractice

import android.app.Application
import androidx.lifecycle.AndroidViewModel
import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData
import androidx.lifecycle.viewModelScope
import kotlinx.coroutines.Dispatchers
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch

class NoteViewModel(application: Application): AndroidViewModel(application) {

    val allNotes: LiveData<List<Note>>
    val repository: NoteRepository

    init {
        val dao = NoteDatabase.getDatabase(application).getNotesDao()
        repository = NoteRepository(dao)
        allNotes = repository.allNotes
    }

    fun deleteNote (note: Note) = viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        repository.delete(note)
    }

    fun updateNote(note: Note) = viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        repository.update(note)
    }

    fun addNote(note: Note) = viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        repository.insert(note)
    }
}
```

I'd like to end my question post with an actual question, but I am very inexperienced and cannot specify the problem. What would be the correct way to set up a ViewModel in Android with Kotlin?

Comment: Have you tried using `by viewModels()`?

Comment: I'm sorry, but where do I need to put "by viewModels()"?

Comment: I tried to replace ```lateinit var viewModel: NoteViewModel``` with ```val viewModel by viewModels<NoteViewModel>()``` and removed the viewModel declaration inside onCreate(), but it still caused the app to crash.

Comment: Please add the stacktrace as well.

Comment: How do I add a stack trace?

Comment: Look at "Logcat" in Android Studio (at the bottom) and copy and paste the angry blob of crap that shows up when the error happens.

Answer (score 0):

Try initialising NoteViewModel like this inside your Activity.

```
private val viewModel: NoteViewModel by lazy {
        ViewModelProvider(this).get(NoteViewModel::class.java)
    }
```

Comment: I replaced the lateinit command with yours yet it still caused the app to crash.